# Where can I find an exhaustive inventory of cards in Ticket to Ride?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I have fallen quite in love with Ticket to Ride on my iPad, but don't have the physical board game. As I attempt to master the game, I'm finding one difficulty, however- I don't have an exhaustive inventory of the destination cards in particular, nor do I know the odds of drawing any one color after a certain number have already been drawn.

Knowing, for example, the number of color cards would give me a better handle on the odds of drawing say, a 6th, 7th, or 8th white. As the game progresses, that is the kind of information that would allow me to plan a route.

Additionally, knowing all the destinations helps me know the best routes to take to maximize my ability to be able to draw a destination card I've already connected. (Even in the classic game, Chicago, New York, Los Angeles, and
Calgary, for example, appear to be far more common then, say, St. Louis.)

So, is there either a published list of all the destination cards, or else is somebody interested in posting the odds for them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The card distribution for train cars is in the [rulebook](http://www.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/content/rules_tt/), it is 8 colors 12 of each, and 14 locomotive wilds.

There are 30 destination tickets, they can be read [here in high resolution](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/299000/ticket-to-ride) with a BGG account. They are listed here

- Denver to El Paso (4)
- Kansas City to Houston (5)
- New York to Atlanta (6)
- Chicago to New Orleans (7), Calgary to Salt Lake City (7)
- Helena to Los Angeles (8), Duluth to Houston (8), Sault Ste Marie to Nashville (8)
- Montreal to Atlanta (9), Sault Ste. Marie to Oklahoma City (9), Seattle to Los Angeles (9), Chicago to Santa Fe (9)
- Duluth to El Paso (10), Toronto to Miami (10)
- Portland to Phoenix(11), Dallas to New York City (11), Denver to Pittsburgh (11), Winnipeg to Little Rock (11)
- Winnipeg to Houston (12), Boston to Miami (12)
- Vancouver to Santa Fe (13), Calgary to Phoenix(13), Montreal to New Orleans (13)
- Los Angeles to Chicago (16)
- San Francisco to Atlanta (17), Portland to Nashville (17)
- Vancouver to Montréal (20), Los Angeles to Miami (20)
- Los Angeles to New York City (21)
- Seattle to New York (22)

Answer (score 3):

While not intended as such, the various aides at BoardGameGeek.com include full lists.

The [t2r route points.xls](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/21490/t2r-route-points-xls) file includes all 30 base tickets.

The [TTR-usa 1910 Ticket Values and City Frequencies.doc](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/23977/ticket-to-ride-usa-1910-ticket-values-and-city-fre) includes all the 1910 tickets.

Answer (score 2):

The [rulebook](http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_en.pdf) indicates that of the 110 train cards, there are 12 each of 8 different colors, plus 14 wilds.